# Como utilizo um "ou" no while em C

Tags: c, while

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação de batalha naval com que o while pare com 2 condições, que são os erros ou acertos do jogador, onde ele pode errar 5 vezes e tem que acertar todos os pontos, que nesse caso é 30.

```
        do{
    mostrarTabuleiro();
    tiro();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}while (erros<5||acertos<30);
```

Queria saber se é algum erro de sintaxe ou se o erro é antes dessa parte.

```
void tiro()
{
    int i,j,teste,cont;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    printf("\nVAMOS ATIRAAR!!\n");
    printf("Digite a linha: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Digite a coluna: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);
if (tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]!=-1)
{
    printf("Nao desperdice seu tempo!!\n");
    printf("Digite uma coordenada válida!\n");
}
else if (tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]==-1)
teste=navios[i-1][j-1];
acertos=0;
erros=0;
switch (teste)
        {
        case 1:
            erros=erros+1;
            tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]=teste;
            printf("VOCE ERROU\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]=teste;
            acertos=acertos+1;
            printf("Voce acertou um Submarino (2 espaços)\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]=teste;
            acertos=acertos+1;
            printf("voce acertou um contratorpedeiro (3 espaços)\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]=teste;
            acertos=acertos+1;
            printf("voce acertou um navio-tanque (4 espaços)\n");
            break;
        case 5:
            tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]=teste;
            acertos=acertos+1;
            printf("voce acertou um porta-aviões (5 espaços)\n");
            break;
        }
}
```

Aqui está o void tiro, onde esta a condição de parada.

Comment: A sua condição `do_while` está correta. Execute o programa com um debugger para saber a linha do erro.

Comment: Você poderia tentar separar o operador, dessa forma: while (erros < 5 || acertos < 30), ou até assim: while ((erros < 5) || (acertos < 30))

Comment: Não há erro de sintaxe no código, apesar de pouco legível, a não ser que a funções e variáveis envolvidas não existem. Que erro ocorre? Onde? precisa de mais contexto, olhando só isto não dá para saber.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Penso que o teu problema esta no método tiro, esta dentro de um "do while", sempre que entras no método e o utilizador introduz uma coordenada válida estas a fazer:

```
else if (tabuleiro[i-1][j-1]==-1)
teste=navios[i-1][j-1];
acertos=0;
erros=0;
switch (teste)
  (...)
```

Cada vez que o utilizador introduz as coordenadas correctas, voltas a meter os valores a 0 na próxima iteração, logo, a tua variável acertos e erros vão sempre ter o valor 0 e 1, nunca superior a isso o que faz um ciclo infinito.

Para facilitar, podes substituir os valores:

```
acertos=acertos+1;
erros=erros+1;
```

Por:
    acertos++;
    erros++;
Que incrementa 1 a variável, caso pretendas increventar outro valor podes fazer:
    acertos += x;
    erros += x;
Sendo x um valor a tua escolha, o += substitui:

**variavel = variavel +**